# React-native ui-kitten select not working smooth, taking delay on select item

Tags: react-native, select, react-native-ui-kitten

I am using @ui-kitten/components in my react-native project, and it's component select I've using it

Here is my code for selectbox:

```
        const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(new IndexPath(0));
        const languageData = ['Select language', 'English', 'Hindi'];
        const displayValue = languageData[selectedIndex.row];

        const renderOption = title => <SelectItem title={title} key={title} />;


                     <Select
                      value={displayValue}
                      selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                      onSelect={index => {
                        {
                          setSelectedIndex(index);
                          setFieldValue('language', displayValue);
                        }
                      }}
                      label={evaProps => (
                        <Text {...evaProps}>{'Native language'}</Text>
                      )}>
                       {languageData.map(renderOption)}
                    </Select>
```

setFieldValue value I am using for formik validation on submit button.

After selecting any item not working smoothly and taking delay of 5 seconds